# Multi-admins/fabrics in Matter protocol

Tags: smart-home, esp32, linux, smart-lights, matter

I am a newbie Matter protocol developer.

I am trying multi-admins/fabrics features. Could you please tell me how many ways to add a new admin into a node? Is the way to add without re-open the commissioning window? I have read a blog about multi-admins using edit ACLs is here: https://grandcentrix.net/en/blog/matter_01/.
[image]

Description about my project:

- Device 1: Linux PC is the matter controller role (using in the first commissioning)
- Device 2: ESP32 is running lighting-app (end-device node role).
- Device 3: Another Linux PC is the matter controller (new admin).

Comment: all capitals is equivalent to shouting ... please fix the title